# Problem with showing loading spinner while charts are loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

In my html, css, and vanilla js project, I have a `getWorldChartsData` which shows four charts like so:

[image: image of charts]

I want to show a loading spinner while we're waiting for the charts to load but I'm having problems.

This is the function that is retrieving data for these charts:

```
function getWorldChartsData() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.charts__loading-spinner');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
  chartsData.forEach(function (chartData, index) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(elems);
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          elems[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        const res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        chartData.data = res.Data.Data.map(function (d) {
          return d.high;
        }).filter(function (d, i) {
          return [0, 4, 9, 13, 17, 20, 23].includes(i);
        });

        drawWorldPriceCharts();
        updateAJAXLoaders();
      }
    };
    
    xhr.open('GET', chartData.apiURL, true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

And as you can see, I'm trying to toggle showing the loading spinner with changing its `display` to `block` and `none`.

This is the HTML for the charts:

```
         <ul class="charts__chart-cards">
            <li class="charts__chart-card positive-change">
              <div class="chart__loading-spinner" class="center">
                <img src="assets/images/loading-spinner.svg" alt="loading-spinner">
              </div>
              <div class="charts__chart-symbol-container">
                <img
                  data-ajax="icon_BTCUSDT"
                  data-format="src"
                  class="ajax-load charts__chart-symbol-icon"
                />
                <h4
                  class="ajax-load charts__chart-symbol-name"
                  data-ajax="symbol_BTCUSDT"
                >
                  ETH/USDT
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="charts__chart-prices-container">
                <span
                  class="ajax-load charts__chart-price"
                  data-ajax="volume_BTCUSDT"
                  data-format="currency"
                  data-currency="$"
                  >5678</span
                >
                <span
                  class="ajax-load charts__chart-price-change"
                  data-ajax="change_BTCUSDT"
                  >+1.945%</span
                >
              </div>
              <div class="ct-chart charts__chartist-world-price"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed for solving this problem.

**EDIT:** I deleted the code for three charts in my `html` to make it shorter and readable. Just know that there are 3 more `li` elements like this one, each of them responsible for one chart.

Comment: Hi, please leave only relevant minimal code fir your problem

Comment: @OmriAttiya I have only added the code that I mentioned in my problem. How do you suggest I make it less?

Comment: What's the behavior you have now?

Comment: Omri is right because than it's more easy to search for the issue. But based on the code you've placed here so far, I guess it's the for loop over the elements inside the chartsData.forEach.  Instead of this for loop inside, try elems[index].style.display = 'none'; Otherwise it will loop over all the loaders for every chart.

Comment: @OmriAttiya the charts are showing up fine (like the image I attached but loading spinner functions are doing nothing.

Comment: @arvie okay I'll try to summarize my code a bit but I don't understand why you mean by elems[index].style.display='none'. Isn't it already like that? what should I change?

Comment: @NewshaNik I've added a code section in an answer here below. Hopefully it will make it more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's the for loop over the elements inside the chartsData.forEach.
The first item of chartsData in this foreach loop will set the display none for all the loaders because of the for loop try to use elems[index].style.display = 'none';  instead so the code will be like:

```
function getWorldChartsData() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.charts__loading-spinner');
 
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'block';
  }

  chartsData.forEach(function (chartData, index) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {                
        elems[index].style.display = 'none';

        const res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

        chartData.data = res.Data.Data.map(function (d) {
          return d.high;
        }).filter(function (d, i) {
          return [0, 4, 9, 13, 17, 20, 23].includes(i);
        });

        drawWorldPriceCharts();
        updateAJAXLoaders();
      }
    };
    
    xhr.open('GET', chartData.apiURL, true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```